# When using Global Query Filters, tenant Id is null when I try to get roles to update the claims

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to set up multitenancy in the application that I'm working on. I added the Global Query Filters and implemented the TenantProvider as suggested [here](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-global-query-filters/). Note this block of code in the example that I listed:

```
public interface ITenantProvider
{
    Guid GetTenantId();
}
 
public class DummyTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    public Guid GetTenantId()
    {
        return Guid.Parse("069b57ab-6ec7-479c-b6d4-a61ba3001c86");
    }
}
```

In my case, instead of the `DummyTenantProvider`, I have implemented the tenant provider that gets tenantId from the `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.GetTenantId()`. I understand that the type of `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User` is of `ClaimsPrincipal`, so I added the additional method that accepts `this ClaimsPrincipal` as parameter and returns tenantId:

```
public static string GetTenantId(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    return principal.FindFirstValue("tenant");
}
```

Also, I've implemented the Api Authentication with JWT token. In Startup.cs, I added the registration of the authentication like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // some code that is not relevant
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    // some code that is not relevant

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            // here I get the needed service and from that service, I get the data that I need for Claims (Roles are needed)
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                            {
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roles)),
                            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
            context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
        },
    };
});
```

Now, the issue that I'm having is when I'm making an HTTP request that's targeting the method in the controller that gets roles for the user (the method is using the same service I'm using in the code above) when debugging the code, first the `OnTokenValidated` is called and the roles for the user should be populated and added to claims, and then the method in the controller is called. When the `OnTokenValidated` calls the service and when the request to the database is executed (simple "dbContext.Roles.ToListAsync()" in the repository), the global query filter is applied and tenantId should be added to that database request. But when the global filter is applied, tenantId is null in the `GetTenantId` method and the code throws `ArgumentNullException` error. What I can't figure out is why is the tenantId null. My assumption is that when the service is called from `OnTokenValidated`, that is not the part of the HTTP request, and then the `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` doesn't have the needed value, but I'm not sure if I'm right about that.
I would appreciate some additional insight into what I'm doing wrong here.
If anything else is needed to make things clearer, I'm happy to edit the question.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in need of a solution, I was able to resolve this issue by adding the Tenant Id as a new claim in `Startup.cs` using the `TokenValidatedContext` (because I have that information in `TokenValidatedContext` at that moment). Looks something like this:

```
ctx.HttpContext.User.Identity?.AddClaim(New Claim('tenant'));
```

Later in the Tenant Provider I have access to this claim.